# How to keep away or avoid a loud coworker

Tags: colleagues

How do I keep myself away from a loud coworker. That person is way too loud on the phone, in the meetings and everywhere. I can hear them type the keys on the keyboard so hard, that I dread the keyboard might break apart.
I can literally hear the sound of them chewing their food. It is driving me nuts.

I tried using loud voice on my headphones, but does not help.
Looking for innovative ways to keep away from them.

Comment: Have you discussed this with the colleague in question?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Actually, noise-cancelling headphones will make the problem worse.  (Most) active noise-cancelling headphones are very good at cancelling out repeating noise, like jet engine noise, traffic, air handlers, etc.  However, they don't cancel out voice and other non-repeating patterns (like the click on a keyboard), and make them perceptually even louder.  Good subjective review:  http://superuser.com/a/114586/227392

Comment: Yes, I did try the noise cancellation but does not help.. There are times when the coworker is just banging the desk out of frustration or whatever, but that is not how they are supposed to behave! I am not sure how to get this to the notice of their manager. We do not share the same manager.

Comment: @Erik Well, I tried to talk, but the coworker is not the friendly kind, does not react to a simple hello in the morning! So I am not sure how to take it forward